# How to make a search dialog with ActionBarSherlock?(not search)

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

Good day!
He did everything on [article from google](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html), but used ActionbarSherlock with its implementation SearchView, but the requests dont send in to SearchActivity.
Can anyone of you know what could be the problem. The request is sent only when you push the button "enter" on the keyboard, and I would like to make it work similarly "live search", once started to enter, immediately went searching.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              package="ru.ex.Interface"
              android:versionCode="45"
              android:versionName="2.2.1b"
              android:installLocation="auto"
            >

        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>




        <application
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.Custom"

                >


            <!-- enable the search dialog to send searches to SearchableActivity -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                       android:value=".SearchActivity"/>

            <activity
                    android:name=".SearchActivity"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                    android:parentActivityName=".MainFragmentActivity"
                    android:launchMode="singleTop"
                    >
                <!-- This intent-filter identifies this activity as "searchable" -->

                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>

                <!-- This metadata entry provides further configuration details for searches -->
                <!-- that are handled by this activity. -->

                <meta-data
                        android:name="android.app.searchable"
                        android:resource="@xml/search_config" />

            </activity>

            <activity
                    android:name=".MainFragmentActivity"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                    android:launchMode="singleTask"
                    >

                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>

            </activity>

        </application>


    </manifest>
```

**Crating menu in MainFragmentActivity**

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {

        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.serch_menu, menu);            
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search_menu).getActionView();            
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));            
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); 
        return true;
    }
```

**SearchActivity.java**

```
public class SearchActivity extends CustomMenuFragmentActivity
{


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle save)
    {
        super.onCreate(save);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_page);
        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction()))
        {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            goSearch(query);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void goSearch(final String s)
    {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To search continuously as the user types, set a query text listener.

SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() 
    {
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) 
        {
            goSearch(newText);
            return true;
        }

```
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) 
    {
        goSearch(query);
        return true;
    }
};
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
```

However, it looks like your application isn't set up for this kind of continuous searching.  You have the SearchView in the menu in your MainActivity, but launch the SearchActivity to show results.  Instead, your SearchView menu item needs to be in the same activity that will be showing results, and your goSearch() method should update the activity's contents when new results are found.

Answer (score 0):

This is a code snippet from a project I wrote recently which has search functionality of a `ListView` alongside `ActionBarSherlock`:

```
// Create a new search view on the ActionBar
SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
// Set the hint inside the search box
searchView.setQueryHint("Search...");
// When the user inputs text, filter the FAQs
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        // adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        // adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
        return true;
    }
});
// Create a "search" menu option to search the list
MenuItem item = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, Menu.NONE, R.string.search).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_search).setActionView(searchView);
item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
```

Just replace the commented `adapter.getFilter()` with whatever you need.